# restore disk backup by writing only non-zero blocks

Tags: dd, disk-image, thinpool

Assuming you have a disk backup in raw format `sda.img` and `/dev/sda` is initially filled with zeroes, how to skip zeroes while restoring the backup? An analog of `dd` should detect zero block in input stream and perform an appropriate seek on output device.

**Note**

I tried `cp` option `--sparse=always`, but it looks ineffective, if destination is a block device:

```
[root@vmarch ~]# truncate sda.img -s1G
[root@vmarch ~]# cat sda.img | cp --sparse=always /dev/stdin sdb.img
[root@vmarch ~]# du -h sda.img sdb.img
0       sda.img
0       sdb.img
[root@vmarch ~]# ls -lh sda.img sdb.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.0G Jul 31 09:17 sda.img
-rw------- 1 root root 1.0G Jul 31 09:17 sdb.img
[root@vmarch ~]# losetup -f sdb.img
[root@vmarch ~]# losetup
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE     DIO
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /root/sdb.img   0
[root@vmarch ~]# cp --sparse=always sda.img /dev/loop0
[root@vmarch ~]# du -h sda.img sdb.img
0       sda.img
1.1G    sdb.img
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand or agree with your assumptions, which makes answering the question a bit touchy.  Are you aware that unused sectors may not be filled with zeros and that used sectors could include zeros?

Comment: You possibly want the `sparse` option to `dd`, but unless you _know_ your device is full of NULs before you start then @JuliePelletier's warning is very apt; the resulting filesystem may not be valid!

Comment: @JuliePelletier it's a virtual disk I have just created. Unfortunately I can't use host tools to fill it, only guest tool

Comment: @basin:  In most cases, especially for a one-shot like this, I wouldn't waste time wondering if it'll be ok and then end up wasting many more hours on troubleshooting issues, I'd just let it do the copy as intended even if it could potentially be optimized.

Comment: you should also rethink your assumption that "dd is a good, or even reasonable, tool to use for backups".

Answer (score 0):

With GNU coreutils (e.g. on non-embedded Linux), you can use `cp --sparse=always` to make the output file as sparse as possible:

```
cp --sparse=always sda.img /dev/sda
```

This may or may not be faster than a straight

```
cat sda.img >/dev/sda
```

`cp --sparse=always` has to spend more time reading and analyzing its input. The `cat` version spends more time writing, but unless the output device is slow, that's not going to affect the duration of the copy much, since in this scenario the reading and writing can mostly be parallelized.

Comment: Sorry, your solution doesn't work. See "Note" in my question